# Function Pointers stored in global variables get set to 0 when entering function, and get back to previous state when exiting function

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, function-pointers

I like to program as an hobby, and as such I usually have a lot of fun going really low level.

In the past few days I've learned about the Windows API, how to set up a window, open it and manage the messsage queue.

To render I've decided to use OpenGL, and have started learning it. Without using libraries like GLEW that automatically load all the functions I had to do all of that manually.

Everything was actually going fine. I managed to load all the function pointers correctly and store them in global variables to be accessed by anyone including this .h file:

```
#pragma once

#include "glCoreARB.h"
#include "wglExt.h"

#define internal static

extern "C"
{
 //FUNCTION POINTERS
 // Debug/Init Functions
 static PFNGLGETERRORPROC                           glGetError;
 static PFNGLGETINTEGERVPROC                        glGetIntegerv;
 static PFNGLGETSTRINGIPROC                         glGetStringi;
 static PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC                          glGetString;

 ... AND MANY MORE (Not gonna write all of them down, you get it)

 //LOADING FUNCTIONS
    internal void *GetAnyGLFuncAddress(const char *name)
    {
     void *p = (void *)wglGetProcAddress(name);
     if ((p == 0) || (p == (void*)0x1) || (p == (void*)0x2) || (p == (void*)0x3) || (p == (void*)-1))
     {
        HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
        p = (void *)GetProcAddress(module, name);
     }

    return p;
    }

 internal void LoadGLFunc(HDC DeviceContext)
 {
    glGetIntegerv   =    (PFNGLGETINTEGERVPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetIntegerv");
    glGetStringi    = (PFNGLGETSTRINGIPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetStringi");
    glGetString     = (PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetString");
    glGetError      = (PFNGLGETERRORPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetError");

    GLint Version = getGLVersion();
    wglGetExtensionsStringARB = (PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGARBPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("wglGetExtensionsStringARB");
    const char *extensions = wglGetExtensionsStringARB(DeviceContext);

  //Once I got the extensions I Loaded all of those function pointers
  wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB          = (PFNWGLGETPIXELFORMATATTRIBIVARBPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB");

  ... And so on

  //Then based on the available OpenGL Version

  if (Version >= 33)
    {
        glGetShaderiv                       = (PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetShaderiv");
        glGetShaderInfoLog                  = (PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetShaderInfoLog");
        glGetProgramiv                      = (PFNGLGETPROGRAMIVPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetProgramiv");
        glGetProgramInfoLog                 = (PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC)GetAnyGLFuncAddress("glGetProgramInfoLog");

   ... And many more...
```

All of these function pointers are loaded inside my Windows Platform code by a function, The ScreenInfo struct contains the DeviceContext and the WindowHandle that were retrieved beforehand

```
internal VOID Win32_SetupOpenGLRenderingContext(ScreenInfo *Screen)
{
 PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR PixelFormat = {};

PixelFormat.nSize           = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
PixelFormat.nVersion        = 1;
PixelFormat.dwFlags         = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
PixelFormat.iPixelType      = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
PixelFormat.cColorBits      = 32;   //Colordepth of the framebuffer
PixelFormat.cDepthBits      = 24;   //Number of bits for the depthbuffer
PixelFormat.cStencilBits    = 8;    //Number of bits for the stencilbuffer

Screen->DeviceContext       = GetDC(Screen->WindowHandle);
s32 PixelFormatValue        = ChoosePixelFormat(Screen->DeviceContext, &PixelFormat);
SetPixelFormat(Screen->DeviceContext, PixelFormatValue, &PixelFormat);

Screen->RenderingContext    = wglCreateContext(Screen->DeviceContext);
wglMakeCurrent(Screen->DeviceContext, Screen->RenderingContext);

LoadGLFunc(Screen->DeviceContext);
}
```

Now, **UP TO THIS POINT EVERYTHING WORKED PERFECTLY**, all the function pointers were loaded correctly, and I could call all the GL functions inside the Windows Platform Code.

But The Platform Code, obviously, calls the MainLoop of the application inside it's message loop:

```
 while(Running)
{
    MSG Msg;
    while (PeekMessageA(&Msg, Screen.WindowHandle, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        Win32_ProcessKeyboard(&Keyboard, Msg);

        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&Msg);

        if (Keyboard.isQuitting)
        {
            Running = FALSE;
        }
    }

    Loop(&Screen); // THIS FUNCTION HERE!

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (SwapBuffers(Screen.DeviceContext) == FALSE)
    {
        DWORD Error = GetLastError();
        LogError("In swapping buffers error: ", Error);
    }

}
```

RIGHT BEFORE entering the Loop function everything is fine. Here's the Loop function code, which is in another file:

```
 extern "C" void GameLoop(ScreenInfo *Screen)
 {
   RenderTriangle(Screen);

   return;
 }
```

And the RenderTriangle call:

```
 internal void RenderTriangle(ScreenInfo *Screen)
 {
   GLuint shaderProgram;
   GLuint VAO = 0;

   if (Screen->wasTriangleInit == FALSE)
   {
    glViewport(0, 0, Screen->Width, Screen->Height);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    THERE IS MORE TO THIS FUNCTION, BUT THE PROBLEM HAPPENS WAY BEFORE, SO I'M PRETTY SURE IT'S IRRELEVANT.
```

Once I enter The Loop Function from the platform code, **ALL AND ONLY THE POINTERS TO THE GL FUNCTIONS *USED IN THE RenderTriangle* CALL GET SET TO 0x0**

I tried tricking the application, by adding an if(0) {} block on top of everything in the RenderTriangle call to avoid crashing, like this:

```
 internal void RenderTriangle(ScreenInfo *Screen)
 {
   GLuint shaderProgram;
   GLuint VAO = 0;
   if(0)
   {
    if (Screen->wasTriangleInit == FALSE)
    {
     glViewport(0, 0, Screen->Width, Screen->Height);

     glBindVertexArray(VAO);

     GLfloat vertices[] =
     {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
     };
```

Like this, when entering the function, all the pointers still get set to 0x0, but **The moment I come out and re-enter the Windows Platform file, all the function pointers are re-set to the proper values**.

I really have no Idea what to do here or what is happening. Any help?

Comment: It's a good thing that you want to be clear in your message. But that's just too much code. I suggest you to write a [small program that reproduces the error you are trying to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think the guy who answered first got it right. I needed to define all the function pointers as __declspec(selectany)... but I'm not sure what that does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you write in header file

```
static PFNGLGETERRORPROC                           glGetError;
```

every `c/cpp` have own private copy of `glGetError` and it not conflict with other because it `static` - so different `cpp` files use different versions of `glGetError` - in one cpp unit you init one version and it !=0, when you enter to another cpp unit - you worked with uninit version , ant it 0. when you return to original unit - again != 0;
 so problem with bad declaration.

you need declare it as

```
extern PFNGLGETERRORPROC glGetError;
```

in `.h` file and as

`PFNGLGETERRORPROC glGetError;`

in any single cpp. file.

or declare it as

```
__declspec(selectany) PFNGLGETERRORPROC glGetError;
```

Comment: I already have the entire .h file wrapped in extern "C" {} block. The problem is, If I don't make them static, then the linker complains it has multiple definitions of those functions... BUT The __declspec(selectany) WORKS for me, what does it do exactly???

Comment: @Lory - are you understand my answer at all ? `If I don't make them static, then the linker complains it has multiple definitions of those functions` - about this i exactly and write. you have **multiple definitions of those functions**. `with static` keyword you avoid error, but make names private, but you still have **multiple definitions of those functions** and this question nothing about `winapi` - clear `c/c++` question. `what does __declspec(selectany) do exactly` ? you try search [it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tkz6s71.aspx) in google ?